# Do Apple require Network detection for openURL in Safari from your app?

Tags: iphone, reachability, openurl

I am about to submit my first iPhone app to the app store and within the about page, I have a link to our website. Is it ok to allow Safari to open and fail to load if network is not present, or will I be required to use reachability code to detect this beforehand?

I don't want the app to be rejected, so want to cover all bases.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this won't be an issue with the submission process, but hey, it is Apple so you never know. I'd just submit it and see what happens, they are running through submissions pretty quick at this point. If they reject it for that specific reason, you can just fix it and resubmit.

Comment: I just found this on Apples Store Submission Tips part of the developer portal. Appears without it, an app could get rejected, however possibly as Safari will handle the loading of the URL it will not be the case for me:-

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/news/appstoretips/